# WP custom post type - set page as parent

Tags: wordpress

My setup is as follows: 
- custom post type called 'Clients'
- 2 levels of navigation (separate, second level only shows if current page has parent/children)
- a page called Clients
 
- the client posts have a custom template (single-clients.php)

I want to make any 'client' post a subpage/child of the Clients page, so the navigation displays correctly on the clients page (it automatically lists subpages) and it's easy to add new clients.

I have found a couple of scripts, but none of them did exactly what I wanted.

Here's the main part of my sub navig code:

```
<nav id='content_clients_navig' class='navig_general'>
    <ul>
        <?php
            global $post;

            //determine which navig should be displayed
            //if post has parent, display parent navig
            //else display the current post's navig
            $navig_display = ($post->post_parent) ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID;

            $menu_args = array(
                'child_of' => $navig_display,
                'title_li' => ''
            );
            wp_list_pages( $menu_args );
        ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I call it by inserting this piece of code in my template files:

```
<?php if (has_subnavig()) get_template_part( 'part', 'subnavig' ); ?>
```

Here is has_subnavig:

```
function has_subnavig()
    {
        global $post;
        if( is_page() && $post->post_parent){
            return true;
        }else{
          $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
        };
        if($children){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        };
    }
```

Comment: How are you listing your second level navigation? Maybe you need to change that code. Are you using Wordpress Menus?

Comment: I edited the main post, check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to change `has_subnavig` to the following, so that the subnav is also displayed when viewing the parent, or the clients posts:

```
function has_subnavig()
{
    global $post;

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
        // post is child post
        return true;
    } else if ( $post->post_type == 'clients' || $post->post_name == 'clients' ) {
        // post is clients parent or clients post type
        return true;
    } else {
        // determine if post has children
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");

        if ( $children ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        };
    };
}
```

Secondly it's important to know, if the subnavigation should be the clients list, or the standard child pages list. That's why we ask, if the `post_type` or the `post_name` is `clients`. The main part of my sub navig code could be like this:

```
global $post;

// determine which navig should be displayed
if ( $post->post_type == 'clients' || $post->post_name == 'clients' ) {
    // display clients navig if page is clients parent
    // or post_type is clients

    $menu_args = array(
        'child_of' => 0,
        'post_type' => 'clients',
        'post_status' => 'publish' 
    );
} else {
    // if post has parent, display parent navig
    // else display the current post's navig
    $navig_display = ($post->post_parent) ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID;

    $menu_args = array(
        'child_of' => $navig_display,
        'title_li' => ''
    );
}

wp_list_pages( $menu_args );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. There is one little perk with though. When I click on a client, I no longer get the 'current_page_item' class on the main navig, which is pretty important. Also, the subnavig shows the complete page list, which I don't understand.

Comment: When displaying a client, $post->post_type doesn't output anything.